# 'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' when upgrading to .NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to upgrade my .Net core 2.2 application to .net 5.0

This line no longer works:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I get the message:

> 'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IdentityBuilder' could be found

So based on my research I tried:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
   .AddUserStore<DataContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

However, while this compiles I get the following error at runtime:

> Implementation type 'motorsport.Models.DataContext' can't be converted
> to service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`

This is my DataContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Note that my application is API only, I'm not using Razor Views at all.

Comment: AddEntityFrameworkStores should be available in the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace.

Comment: Have you installed  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`?

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you

Comment: Hello,@Robbie Mills,I have posted it as an answer,can you accept it?Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which provides types for persisting Identity data with Entity Framework Core.

Because [AddEntityFrameworkStores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityentityframeworkbuilderextensions.addentityframeworkstores?view=aspnetcore-5.0) has been moved into separate NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`.